# How to mock libraries that are unknown in Javascript on my local environment?

Tags: javascript, mocking

I am developing a website using Javascript for a device which has a particular Javascript library that can be used. This Javascript library is known on the device but it is not known locally. F.e. I execute `library.function()`. For this, locally I get the error: **library is not defined**.

Is there a way to avoid this error locally so that I can test those parts without commenting it out? To mock the libraries that are unknown locally.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? IDE Support? Local development? Test Mocking? The simple things like require something with npm/yarn is already out of question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a global scoped library? If yes, you can substitute it and mock the behaviour:

```
var MockLib = {
   someFunction: () => console.log("someFunction called"),
   someOtherFunc: (args) => console.log("someOtherFunc called", args),
   someProp: "value-123",
};

window.library = window.library || MockLib;
```

Then, executing `library.someFunction()` will execute the function on the library if it was already defined or your mock if not.

Just make sure to put the `window.library` assignment AFTER the library should have been loaded.